# How long to wait before closing a post?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, a bad question (not clear, too broad ...) is asked. As soon as it is asked, it is voted to close and it appears on the Close Votes queue. So it is closed as soon as it is asked if enough reviewers are available online.

There are cases where the OP details his/her question just a couple of dozen minutes later (suppose he got a call that lasts and could not detail his question right away) and before he reacts he finds his question closed/put on hold and he has to edit his question and wait longer for his post to be repoened (hoping he understands how all this works, especially for new users).

- Should not we wait before deciding to close a post?
- If yes, what is the ideal waiting time before closing then? (hoping SE would provide an effective way to resolve this: for example not appearing a question on the Close Votes queue until this optimum wait time is reached)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For questions that can be improved, and specific instruction given to improve it, I personally give 3-4 hours. I have not enough data to determine if that is long or short enough, but it is something I am actively keeping an eye on.

For questions for which no improvement can be made that does not constitute asking a completely different question, I think it is ok to close.

As for the possibility that a valid edit can be made after the window of time has expired, the close text does state:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
>   please edit the question.

It is possible that someone would get frustrated that the question was closed and abandon improving the question, but that balance needs to be watched.

Comment: +1, however I'm wondering [how do you get back to this skipped review 3-4 hours later?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2002/32746) I did not found any practical way to do it...