# How to access skipped reviews?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I'm taking advantage of [another question asked by Begueradj](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2000/32746) to know if there is a way to access previously skipped reviews?

The use-case is as follow:

- There are several close reviews pending,
- One of them concerns a new post from a few minutes ago, so I consider it too new to vote to close it (maybe just put a comment or edit it),
- However there are other posts waiting a review, so I need to click on "Skip" to go to the next post.

Once I have done that, how do I get back to this skipped review a few hours later?

I even looked in my profiles, under the "votes" and "all actions" sections but did not find anything there. However, the review URL itself, when typed directly, still seems to remain valid.

This use-case happens very regularly. My current workaround is just to mostly not bother any more with the close reviews during the day, only on the morning and late afternoon (French time). At times when there are usually a higher ratio of older posts.

Comment: If the review queue is empty, [then yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153451/)! Would that work for your purposes?

Comment: @Pops: I never saw this exact screen, mentioning a matching filter and inviting to see the review history. All I get at the end of the review is "*This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues..

Want to get back to the questions? Return to the Information Security Stack Exchange homepage.*". Most probably this screen and link [only applies to moderator and 10K users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221134/can-our-review-history-also-list-the-items-we-have-skipped/234909#234909).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under [review](https://security.stackexchange.com/review) choose the queue you are interested in. Then click history. You would then end up on [this page](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).

On the bottom on the page you will find a link to show only your own reviews. Once you are seeing only your own reviews there will be a checkbox to include skipped reviews in the list. (The links available at the bottom of the page vary slightly depending on reputation.)